# SOOrder Entry Screen not working

Tags: acumatica

My SOOrder entry screen grid is automatically taking me to the SOOrder page with a new order instead of showing the grid anytime I attempt to navigate to SOOrders.

When I edit the Generic Inquiry, it shows an error next to the Entry Page selector that has SOOrder selected:

[image]

It also does not allow me to select any fields on the Navigation tab -> Field selector to associate with a parameter for the navigation.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: if you open the sales order page, then go to "tools" (or "help" depending on the Acumatica version) in the upper right of the page and click on "web service" do you get any error details?

Comment: Yes I do. It says Graph doesn't contain action named "Create Shipment" under "Action" menu, but it most certainly does.

Comment: I believe that was a bug in 2018R1 when a customization exists on the sales order screen. Have you tried the latest version of 2018R1 (update 5)?

Comment: Not yet, but thanks for the advice. I will advise the customer that it is a known issue and that they will need to upgrade their instance version for a fix.

Comment: I see something in the release notes for 18.103.0022 that might show it resolved in that version. Otherwise try the latest 18.105 to see if that helps.

Comment: Alright, I'll advise the customer on that. Thanks Brendan!

Comment: no problem. Let us know if that fixes your issue

Comment: Is this question about programming?

Comment: any update on this? I got the same issue but on my customized screen